# Kong Ingress Controller: How to remove a plugin entry from a configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, api-gateway, kong

I'm learning [Kong API Gateway](https://github.com/Kong/kong), and I'm trying to configure it using the [Kubernetes Ingress Controller](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller).

I've been able to add a service plugin, following [this tutorial](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/guides/getting-started/#using-plugins-on-services), but I cannot find anywhere **how to remove it**.

I searched it on ChatGPT and I've been able to edit the configuration with `kubectl edit service <service_name>` command, but it seems a little inconvenient and it feels like it's the wrong way to do it.

### Question

What's the correct (simplest and quickest) way to remove a plugin from the configuration of a service?
Perhaps using `kubectl annotate` command?
Links to any useful documentation will be widely appreciated :)

Comment: `kubectl annotate service echo konghq.com/plugins-` . See `kubectl annotate --help`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When applying a plugin using CRDs, It's just a generic Kubernetes object.
Afterward, we can use annotation to annotate a service to have Kong apply said plugin to the service.
If you want to disable a plugin from a service, remove the `konghq.com/plugins` annotation.
To easily remove the annotation, just run `kubectl annotate service <service-name> konghq.com/plugins-`. Using `-` after the annotation name will just remove it from the service.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :) Please let me know if I got it right: passing the manifest to `kubectl apply -f` will create a KongPlugin resource, but it's not yet "enabled" (~associated with the ingress/service). The plugin is effectively added to the configuration and enabled, only after entering `kubectl annotate [...]` command. And is that why, after removing an annotation (`kubectl annotate [...]-`), I can still see the plugin with `kubectl get KongPlugins`, even tough it's not in the configuration anymore?

Comment: @mikyll98 yup, even though the KongPlugin still exists, It's not applied anywhere until the annotation is added to the services/ingress ( or globally via `global: "true"` label)
Think of it like a ConfigMap-ish, just a configuration that could be used to do something, otherwise just existed.